# syntax error on mysql query to update in python

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7

here is my query

```
 x.execute("UPDATE details SET name =%s,"(form.newname)"WHERE name =%s," (form.name))
```

am getting `syntax error`.can anyone pls help to fix it

Comment: Kill the comma after `SET` and add appropriate spacing: `x.execute("UPDATE details SET name = %s"(form.newname)" WHERE name = %s" (form.name))`

Comment: i tried but same error. thanx for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on syntax: cursor.execute(sql_query, args)

It should be like:

```
x.execute("UPDATE details SET name = %s WHERE name = %s", (form.newname, form.name))
```

Comment: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)...am getting like this error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update those name which is ending with the letter "s"

then you have to use LIKE operator in where clause

```
update destails set name ="adfsf" where name like '%s'
```

Comment: am not trying to update  names with letter s .i want to update name from form.name to form.new name<-(these are text boxes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
x.execute("""UPDATE details SET name = "%s" WHERE name = "%s" """, (form.newname, form.name))
```

If `form.newname` and `form.name` are `TEXT` fields in database, you have to pass `%s` with parenthesis `"%s"`